# Interpreting Nyquist plot

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

When implementing the control for my application I got this Nyquist plot which made me flabbergasted.

[image]

If I zoom on the point $-1 + 0j$ I get the following image

[image]

How do I interpret this contour going to infinity? Do I have 1 or 2 counter-clockwise turns around $-1 + 0j$?

Comment: How many integrators does your open loop have?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have 1 counter-clockwise turn around. One trajectory comes from the left, then turns around and then moves to the right as you change the parameters. I think this behavior is normal as you have 1 integrator (PID controller) and you have one pole in s=0. As you change the parameters you annulate some function chunks and you get at s=0. Then you continue changing your parameters and get backwards to the right, though this time the trajectory is different due to the different values your function is taking.